# Android Retrofit: content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: android, post, retrofit

Fairly new to android development. I am trying to use retrofit to send a post request. In my retrofit logs, I am seeing

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

I found that requests will only work if I use the content type:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I have searched the googles and have found no clear way to explicitly set the content type. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

In the class where you define your service, modify the related method to follow the pattern below:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST/GET/PUT/DELETE("/your_endpoint")
Object yourMethodName(@Field("your_field") String yourField,...);
```

Comment: Here is what I am doing:  

@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login/post")
    public void authenticateUserWithUserName(@Field("email") String email,@Query("password") String password,Callback<List<Code1User>> callback);

I get an error message:

Comment: Form-encoded method must contain at least one @Field.

Comment: I changed the second @Query to Field.Worked awesome!

Comment: Worked like a charm.No need to mention header like *@Headers({"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}) in api service.Just followed above answer.

Comment: This is my code: @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/flikad/Api/User/shoppersLogin")
    Call<LoginResponse> userLognin( @Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password); I am still getting error: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://..}

Comment: @MayuraDevani how did you fix the Bad Request issue. I am also getting the same error

Comment: `@FormUrlEncoded` could not work with `GET` method, also `@Field`

Comment: We can use as well "@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> params" in order to post multiple params

Answer (score 16):

In retrofit 2 is a little bit different:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST/GET/PUT/DELETE("/your_endpoint")
Call<Task> createTask (@Field("your_field") String title);
```

Comment: `@FormUrlEncoded` could not work with `GET` method, also `@Field`

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the request header like this :

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

in the interface which has the method declarations.