# What I make wrong in my htttp Post Java in Android using Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, post, http-post, retrofit2

I am trying to do a http Post using retrofit2,

I have the the Technical specifications

[image]

I have an error accepted in the Technical specifications

[image]

And I make the http Post how below. But I always get

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=422, message=Unprocessable Entity, url=https://XXX/api/v1/token/}.
```

Can someone help me?

API Interface:

```
public interface PostService {
   @Headers({
           "Content-type: application/json"
   })
   @POST("api/v1/token/")
   Call<String> sendPosts(@Body Posts posts);
```

}

My Class for the request(POJO):

```
public class Posts {

    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;
    @SerializedName("grant_type")
    private String grant_type;
    @SerializedName("scope")
    private String scope;
    @SerializedName("client_id")
    private String client_id;
    @SerializedName("client_secret")
    private String client_secret;

    public Posts() {
        username = "test";
        password = "test";

    }
}
```

My Retrofit Post request in my Activity:

```
            OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://xxxxxx/")
                    .client(okHttpClientBuilder.build())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            postsService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);  //l'oggetto retrofit deve rispettare ciò che è scritto nell'interfaccia creata PostService

            Posts post = new Posts();

            Call<String> call = postsService.sendPosts(post);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    System.out.println("TEST!!!!!!!!!!!!" +  response.toString());  //Response here 
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you using the correct baseUrl? Or did you just modify it for this post?
In case i would try adding the grant_type as well. Usually it is required when asking an access token

Comment: Also you are sending a json body. You can clearly see that the documentation says that an x-www-form-urlencoded is required

Comment: @FabioPiunti I use the correct BaseUrl ( I modify it for this post). grant_type = "" is good? Yes, I am sending a json body. How can I send an "x-www-form-urlencoded is required".?

Comment: I think you should use password as grant_type. To send a x-www-form-urlencoded see this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291006/android-retrofit-content-type-as-application-x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @FabioPiunti I see (@Field("your_field") String title); . Which is "my field" . username and password are both "test". can you write me down the correct code? I am quite new with retroti2.

Comment: The fields are Username and Password, and maybe also grant_type (Try without and if it doesn't work try with). Maybe i could write something later this evening, when i'm bak from work ;)

Comment: @FabioPiunti thanks for your help. I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the the problem.
As @Fabio Piunti says I have To send a x-www-form-urlencoded,

So I Modified the code as below:

```
public interface PostService {
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    })

    @FormUrlEncoded  //I have added this as well
    @POST("api/v1/token/")
    Call<Posts> sendPosts( @Field("username") String title, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

My request in the Activity now is:

```
  ....

  Call<Posts> call = postsService.sendPosts("test", "test");
    //eseguo la mia chiamata (Call) post
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Posts>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Posts> call, Response<Posts> response) {

            System.out.println("TEST!!!!!!!!!!!!" +  response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Posts> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("TEST Error!!!!!!!!!!!!" + t.toString());

        }

    });
```